# Why do Objective-C files use the .m extension?

Tags: objective-c, file-extension

Since I started learning Objective-C and Cocoa, I've been wondering why they have chosen the extension .m for the implementation files - was it supposed to mean something, or was it just a random letter?

Comment: It's for the *em*plementation.

Comment: I guess this was bothering someone else, so they did a bit of research finding contradicting evidence on the meaning behind .m extension. Ultimately it stands for messages.

For the full read: http://pempek.net/blog/2013/11/30/objective-c-file-extension/&utm_medium=email&utm_source=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly

Comment: `.m` files are implementation files as you said. Knowing Apple likes to prefix everything with `i` it is easy to see that **i**mplementation becomes *mplementation* without said `i`.  Then they just used the first letter of mplementation for the file extension: `m`.

Answer (score 531, accepted):

Today most people would refer to them as "method files", but

> "The .m extension originally stood for
>   "**m**essages" when Objective-C was first
>   introduced, referring to a central
>   feature of Objective-C [...]"

(from the book "[Learn Objective-C on the Mac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218150)" by Mark Dalrymple and Scott Knaster, page 9)

**EDIT:** To satisfy an itch I emailed [Brad Cox](http://www.virtualschool.edu/cox/), the inventor of Objective-C, about the question and he answered with this single line:

> "Because .o and .c were taken. Simple
>   as that."

Here's the email as visual proof:

[image: Visual Proof]

Comment: Brad Cox, RIP. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brad_Cox

Comment: What about .oc? Surely it doesn't have to be a single letter, right?

Comment: Seems it's also taken.

Answer (score 10):

It stands for "methods".  From the [comp.lang.objective-C FAQ](http://nextstep.sdf-eu.org/clocFAQ/#tools-files):

> The organisation of Objective-C source is typically similar to that of C or C++ source code, with declarations and object interfaces going into *header* files named with a .h extension, and definitions and object implementations going in files named with a .m (short for *methods*) extension.

Answer (score 5):

.m files contain the (m)ethods. Possible reason?

Comment: m files might contain (m)ultitude of comments as well! go figure:)