# What does .h and .m stand for?

Tags: c, objective-c, abbreviation

#### Exact duplicate:

> [Why do Objective C files use the .m extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652186/why-do-objective-c-files-use-the-m-extension)

I'm thinking .h stands for header. I suppose .m could stand for main, but I don't know. Do any of you actually *know* this?

Just to clarify, I know what goes in which file.  (i.e. I know the purpose of each file type.) I'm merely curious if the file extension name has any particular meaning.

Answer (score 5):

- h - **header**
- m - **method**

Comment: hmm, i thought it was "H"eader and i"M"plementation

Answer (score 2):

.h stands for header while .m stands for implementation

Answer (score 0):

right, .h stands for the header file. .m is for your code like .cpp in c++

regards,
buk