# Callback from static library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I think this should be simple, but im having a real hard time finding information about this topic. I have made a static library and have no problem getting the basics to work. But im having a hard time figuring out how to make a call back from the static library to the main APP.

I would like my static library to only use one header as front, this header should contain functions like:
requestImage:(NSString *)path;
requestLikstOfSomething:(NSSting *)guid;
and so on..

These functions should do the necessary work and start a async NSURLConnection, and call back to the main application when the call have finished. How do you guys do this, what are the best ways to callback from a static library when a async method is finished? should i do this with delegates (is this possible), notifications, key/value observers. I really want to know how you guys have solved this, and what you regard as the best practices.

Im going to have 20-25 different calls so i want the static library header file to be as simple as possible preferable only with a list of the 20-25 functions.

UPDATE:
My question is not how to use delegate pattern, but witch way is the best to do callbacks from static librarys. I would like to use delegates but i dont want to have 20-25 protocol declarations in the public header file. I would prefer to have only one function for each request.

Solution choosen:
i choose the solution from erkanyildiz with the help of a target parameter, i know its pretty low tech, but it was for me the cleanest solution. My goal was to keep the header file as small as possible. Thanks to everybody for they input, i will for sure look more into borrrdens solution with grand central dispatch when i get the time. user1055604 solution with a couple of "standard" delegates for replys is also one i like. So again thank you all for inputs.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards
Morten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegation pattern is a good way to do it.

You can check these pages:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#Objective-C_example

As another approach, you can use a target parameter in every method you have. 
And schedule callbacks on those targets, checking if they are responding to your callbacks using `respondsToSelector`

Comment: Hi. I would prefer to do this with delegations but to my understanding then i would have to put the protocol declaration in the .h file and with 20-25 different callbacks it would be a very overfilled header file. I would prefer not to have protocols declaration in the static library header file. Am i wrong about this ? The target, selector solution seems pretty easy to implement, only problem i can think of is the user of the static library have to give the correct prarameter on the selector or just implement a function defined by me.

Comment: Why do you hesitate to have 20-25 protocol methods. If you need them, you need them.

Comment: I see your point, but im making this library for a client who wish to distribute it, so my goal is to make it as simple as possible to use so as little noice in the header file as possible. But if this is not possible i will be forced to do it with protocols in the header file.

Comment: UIApplicationDelegate Protocol has 21 methods, UIScrollViewDelegate protocol has 13 methods. Don't mind number of methods you have.

Answer (score 0):

Look here for an example with delegates: [How to perform Callbacks in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015608/how-to-perform-callbacks-in-objective-c/1015959#1015959).

It shouldn't matter that the `callback` is executing from within a `static library`.

Static libraries are a compile/link time phenomenon. As such, calls `to` and `from within` static libraries are transparent to the application at runtime.

Comment: Hi. I would prefer to do this with delegations but to my understanding then i would have to put the protocol declaration in the .h file and with 20-25 different callbacks it would be a very overfilled header file. I would prefer not to have protocols declaration in the static library header file. Am i wrong about this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather not have one callback protocol declaration for each function in your static library, start with looking at what each callback would return if you did, forcefully, implement it as a callback.

From there on, find what's in common between them and bind the common elements together in a class which will serve as an interface for the responses. You may need more that one such class.

As an example, look at [NSURLResponse](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

---

> NSURLResponse declares the *programmatic interface* for an object that accesses the response returned by an NSURLRequest instance.
>
> NSURLResponse *encapsulates* the metadata associated with a URL load in a manner independent of protocol and URL scheme.

This class is used by [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) in its `didReceiveResponse` delegate method. In the worse case, you will end up with a couple of callbacks instead of a *noisy* header file. Happy coding. :-)

Comment: Ok i see what you say, i can maybe cut the 20-25 protocols down to lets say two respons protocols one for NSData and one for lets say UIImage. this is definitely. Thanks for you input.

Comment: does this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

Try making your function calls using Grand Central Dispatch.  It's quite simple, and very powerful.  Here is a sample of how to make an async call with a callback:

http://pastebin.com/xDUKm6wh

This paste bin is complaining about errors, but take note of the pattern.  It should work just fine.