# Adding a completion call back for MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, mbprogresshud

I would like to add a completion callback on my method so that the progress of the HUD knows it is complete.

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Loading";
[self doSomethingInBackgroundWithProgressCallback:^(float progress) {
hud.progress = progress;
} completionCallback:^{
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}];
```

What would I need to add to my method to confirm it is complete, or trigger this completionCallback from above?

In this case my method could be anything for example:

```
-(void)doSomethignInBackgroundWithProgressCallback {
sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of `HUD` you can use its `delegate` function `hudWasHidden` which will when you use `HUD` like this -

```
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(your_function) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

and if you want to know how to use `callbacks` in `objective c` then follow this post -

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015608/how-to-perform-callbacks-in-objective-c
```

completion callback method -

```
- (void) doSomethingInBackground:(void (^) (void)) completion
{
    // do your job here

    completion();
}
```

Comment: Using the showWhileExecuting does not increase the progress of the progress bar within the HUD though correct? Which I presume is what the callback part is for?

Comment: are you talking about HUD's progress view progress then you can increase the progress through showWhileExecuting.

Comment: yes if i only use the showWhileExecuting(method) then the progress for the AnnularDeterminate mode of HUD the progress bar in the HUD does not increase at all... I presumed using the above style with the Callback for completition would update the process.

Comment: are you able to help with the callback in the above code example for an example on this?