# Creating my own custom button selector in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

what I want to do is I created my own button class but I need to provide the ability for the developer to have their own button callback.

For example, I can declare a new button in this way:

```
Button* myButton = [[Button alloc] init];
// What I want is something like this
[myButton setSelector: @selector(callMe)];

// and I have this method implemented
- (void)callMe
{
    NSLog("I'm being called");
}
```

Inside my button class I need to have one variable to store what function it will be calling.
For example, in my Button class:

```
if (onButtonClick)
   [self callSelector];
```

How can I do that?

EDIT:
I've found a solution here:
[How to perform Callbacks in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015608/how-to-perform-callbacks-in-objective-c)

Comment: You can use `NSInvocation`, `SEL` & target pair, blocks, delegates, or many other callback types.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
if (onButtonClick)
   [self performSelector:callSelector];
```

Good time to [read up on the base class of all Objective-C classes (NSObject)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) because you'll need stuff like that quite regularly.

Comment: I know about this, but I want to know is there any way I can store which function to be called?
I did think of using delegate but I found out that's not really suit in my case...
Basically what i want is something like CCMenuItem.. when I init I can pass in the @selector(someFunc:)... I dig in the codes and notice they are using block to do it, I was thinking is there any other ways?