# Why is the content of main.m different to other classes?

Tags: objective-c, program-entry-point

so what I'm trying to say is that the "main" method in main.m file does not have a - or + prefix and the parameters are in parenthesis w/o any colons. So what is it all about? Looks like c-style :P Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because it **is** a C function but it calls *NSApplicationMain*. NSApplicationMain is just the entry point for *Cocoa* applications. The arguments passed function exactly the same way as well. *NSApplicationMain* can be thought of as a second, inner *main* function, which is called by the first *main*.

As to why it is called .m, there is another question here that gets answered: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652186/why-do-objective-c-files-use-the-m-extension)

Comment: Okay I understood that it's c-style but is it really pure c-language or just c-style? If c-language then why is it .m file not an .mm or .c? And why can't that just be objective c as well?

Comment: This is so that you can mix Objective C and C code. **.m** can be written in both C and Obj C.

Comment: The main function is indeed pure C.

Comment: Then what's the need of mixing too programming languages? Isn't one just enough?

Comment: @Jf1nG That is an entire other question that is way too long for me to answer ;)

Comment: @Jf1ng Essentially, "almost" all C code is backwards compatible with Objective C, as Objective C is a superset of C. It is the same case with C++ for the most part. But again, the answer as to why it is necessary is complex and long.

Comment: @Jf1ng Some libraries are written in C must be called with native C for example.

Comment: @Jf1ng not trying to boost rep or anything. But normally it is good to accept an answer if it helps you. If it didn't help you, feel free to not worry about it, but atleast for the future ;)